# How do I simplify the code in C#?

Tags: c#, .net

Here is a code I want to simplify:

```
public void Method1(Context context, EventLog log = null)
{
    Class myClass = ConvertToMyClass();
    ApiCall1 apiCall = new ApiCall1(context);
    if (log != null)
    {
        eventLog.WriteEntry("Starting");
    }

    try
    {
        apiCall.Call1(myClass, null, false);
        IsCallSuccess = true;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        if (log != null)
        {
            eventLog.WriteEntry("error");
        }

        IsCallSuccess= false;
        CallErrorMessage = e.Message;
    }
}

public void Method2(Context context, EventLog log = null)
{
    Class myClass = ConvertToMyClass();
    ApiCall2 apiCall = new ApiCall2(context);
    if (log != null)
    {
        eventLog.WriteEntry("Starting");
    }

    try
    {
        apiCall.Call1(myClass);
        NewItemID = myClass.ItemID;
        IsCallSuccess = true;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        if (log != null)
        {
            eventLog.WriteEntry("error");
        }

        IsCallSuccess= false;
        CallErrorMessage = e.Message;
    }
}

public void Method3Context context, EventLog log = null)
{
    Class myClass = ConvertToMyClass();
    ApiCall3 apiCall = new ApiCall3(context);
    if (log != null)
    {
        eventLog.WriteEntry("Starting");
    }

    try
    {
        apiCall.Call3(myClass, "param1");
        UpdatedItemID = myClass.UpdatedItemID;
        IsCallSuccess = true;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        if (log != null)
        {
            eventLog.WriteEntry("error");
        }

        IsCallSuccess= false;
        CallErrorMessage = e.Message;
    }
}
```

There are 3 methods. I've been thinking about how I could simplify them using delegates or lambdas and didn't find anything.

Note that ApiCall1/2/3 are all defined in a third-party library.
Your thoughts?

Comment: Do ApiCall1/2/3 all implement the same base class or interface?

Comment: Yes, they do...

Answer (score 4):

Alright, let's see if we can <s>simplify</s>abstract this for you. I'm not going to say simplify because often times abstracting something is far from simplifying it.

I **think** you can turn the method into something like this:

```
public void Method<T>(Context context, Action<T, Class> body, EventLog log = null)
{
    Class myClass = ConvertToMyClass();
    T apiCall = Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T), new [] { context });
    if (log != null)
    {
        eventLog.WriteEntry("Starting");
    }

    try
    {
        body(apiCall, class);
        IsCallSuccess = true;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        if (log != null)
        {
            eventLog.WriteEntry("error");
        }

        IsCallSuccess = false;
        CallErrorMessage = e.Message;
    }
}
```

... then you should be able to call it like this:

```
// Method1
Method<ApiCall1>(
    yourContextInstance,
    (apiCall, myClass) =>
    {
        apiCall.Call1(myClass, null, false);
    },
    yourLogInstance);

// Method2
Method<ApiCall2>(
    yourContextInstance,
    (apiCall, myClass) =>
    {
        apiCall.Call1(myClass);
        NewItemID = myClass.ItemID;
    },
    yourLogInstance);

// Method3
Method<ApiCall3>(
    yourContextInstance,
    (apiCall, myClass) =>
    {
        apiCall.Call3(myClass, "param1");
        UpdatedItemID = myClass.UpdatedItemID;
    },
    yourLogInstance);
```

... one caveat is `NewItemID` and `UpdatedItemID`. If you're not making these calls from inside the class `Method` is defined in, you may need to modify this a tad to get the `Method` to return and integer instead.

Comment: Instead of `Activator.CreateInstance()`, you could use another delegate to make it more type-safe.

Comment: I agree with svick.